# How can I strip all non-letters from string and convert spaces to dashes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

This simple regex is troubling me.  Can you lend a hand?

How can I get `Foo's Bar` to return `foos-bar` in javascript?

```
var str = "Foo's Bar";
str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace('/[^a-zA-Z-]/g', '').toLowerCase();
return str;
```

The best I can do is `foo's-bar`, leaving the `'`.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be `/[^a-zA-Z-]/g`, not `'/[^a-zA-Z-]/g'`

Comment: Doh!  Well that was easy.  Thanks.  Submit an answer and it'll earn you 5pts.  ;)

Comment: With [RegEx](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: @Ryan meh, my connection crashed, give them to Stecman :P

Comment: Yeah I think SO just went down for a minute

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esailija is spot on - your regex is correct, but the second one is being interpreted as a string since it's wrapped in quotes. With that fixed, your code works perfectly:

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-zA-Z-]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reversing the order and generically avoiding word and space characters

```
str.replace(/[^\w\s]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,"-").toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Regex pattern should not be quoted (first parameter in your second `replace`)
2. Return value needs to be assigned back to `str`

---

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/[^a-zA-Z-]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```